# Stub Not Generated using Sun Wireless toolkit 2.5.2 on Windows xp

Tags: web-services, blackberry, stub, sun, java-wireless-toolkit

I am trying to generate stub using the sun's wireless toolkit 2.5.2 .The os on my pc is windows xp.I am trying to generate stub by using following process

```
Start -> SunWirelessToolkit -> Utilities -> stub generator -> launch
```

then i put the wsdl link of my webservice in that

and specify the output path but now file or output is created in the specified folder.

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong or y that stub is not generated.Wen I copy and paste that url on browser it opens and shows whole wsdl.

I want to generate this stub to consumne webservices in Blackberry.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: it is not giving any error . no file is created on the specified location

Comment: So you are filling the 3 fields and no output message?

Comment: A firewall might be preventing the tool from connecting to the net. Let's do this: open the WSDL file in your browser, then save the descriptor as "descriptor.wsdl" in your workstation. Try again with stub generator this time pointing to your local file.

Comment: @MisterSmith : yes i am filling all three fields and getting no output

Comment: @MisterSmith : please tell me how to save descriptor file ?

Comment: In your browser, File -> "save page as", type in a name followed by the ".WSDL" extension, and you'll be done. (Is the same procedure as saving a web page in local, but changing the output file extension).

Comment: @MisterSmith yes i have done it but wen i browse for file name it doesnot show that wsdl file

Comment: That is because of you not changing the file extension to wsdl as I already told you. C'mon, man, it's only saving a web page with a different extension, nothing difficult. Probably you saved a file like "mypage.wsdl.html" but this is a browser user-level problem.

Comment: yup i saved it as wsdl still no output no error

Comment: Can't believe there are no errors nor timeouts! I've used that very version of stub generator and it didn't gave me any problems. Anyway, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably having a connection timeout or the stub generator is unable to connect due to a firewall.

Try downloading the WSDL file to local and try again.

I cannot understand why the stub generator produces no output nor gives any error. Try putting a bad URL on purpose to see if it fails. If still no output, you probably have the J2ME wireless toolkit or Java bad installed.

UPDATE:
Check this link: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/

Scroll to the middle of the page and you'll find a table with the supported data types. JSR-172 is a JAX-RPC subset, so not all complex types are often supported. Check your WSDL doesn't contain any unsupported type.